# __add__ method in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue

So I'm making my first program in python 3 with operators overloading, and I'm stucked over the **add** (+) operator.

```
def __add__(self, newMember):
    if(isinstance(newMember, Queue)):
       tempList=self.myQueue[:] # makes a copy
       tempList.extend(newMember.myQueue)
       return Queue(tempList)

def __str__(self):
    if not self.myQueue:
        string="."
    else:
        string=""
        for x in self.myQueue:
            string=string+str(x)
            if(x<len(self.myQueue)):
                string=string+", "
            else:
                string=string+"."
    return string
```

basically I'm making a Queue class (I know there's already such one exists), then connecting two Queue objects by typing c=c1+c2. But when I print (c), it messed up the "," and the ".". Can't get what's wrong. 
Any help?

Comment: Shouldn't you do `tempList = Queue(self.myQueue)` or something like that? I don't know much about Python but if you just assign `self.myQueue` to `tempList` then maybe `tempList` refers to the same object as `self.myQueue`...

Comment: I edited my question. I really did reffered to the same object, so I added [:]. I don't want tempList to be a Queue type but a List type so I can return Queue(list)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question (which should probably be a separate question on SO, rather than editing this one):

`if(x<len(self.myQueue)):` is checking whether the value of a string is less than an integer length of a list. This doesn't make any sense, and will always be False.

You could rewrite the entire method as:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ', '.join(str(x) for x in self.myQueue) + '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you set `tempList` to `self.myQueue`, then modify it.
This changes *both* Queues. you want to copy `myQueue`, not share the reference.

with tmplist = queue, both variables point to the ***same*** Object.
Maybe this will help to understand:

```
>>> queue = []
>>> tmplist = queue
>>> tmplist.append(1)
>>> tmplist
[1]
>>> queue
[1]
>>> tmplist = queue[:] #make a copy
>>> tmplist.append(1)
>>> tmplist
[1, 1]
>>> queue
[1]
```

Comment: Thanks ! Now c1 really doens't change. But i still can't print perfectly, it keep messing up "," and ".". I edited the question adding my __str__ code